# How to manage POSIX users in an LDAP directory easily?

Tags: linux, ldap, user-management

I have a directory of POSIX users and groups in a remote [OpenLDAP](http://www.openldap.org/) server. Initially I have about 50 users to setup but I expect to eventually have about 250 that need semi-regular admin attention. For the most part these are pretty basic user setups with one group per user and should follow the posixAccount and posixGroup schemas.

I would like an interface that makes it relatively painless to add users and groups, change user details and reset passwords. I would appreciate if it kept track of UID numbers for me so I didn't have to remember what the next available slot is when adding users.

I would be happiest with a Linux command line solution, but would be willing to use a desktop GUI or self-hosted webapp as well. It doesn't have to handle every LDAP edge case as long as posix account administration is streamlined.

The obvious choice in this space seems to be [phpLDAPadmin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpldapadmin) and I have it running, but it's butt ugly and a pain in the butt to use. While it seems to be able to handle the complexities of LDAP, the user experience is a spectacular failure. Form errors force you to start all over from scratch. the browser back button logs you out. You can't deep link to items or browse the tree (e.g. to find the last used UID!) while you are adding and entry, etc.I'm looking for a less painful admin experience.

Comment: Is the title synonym to "How to manage POSIX users in an LDAP directory easily?"

Comment: My favorite desktop-based LDAP management tool is Apache Directory Studio - may be it will help you